# MVC 4 Kendo UI Grid Column Names

Tags: sorting, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI Grid and trying to do server side paging/sorting using Ajax. My sample server side method for listing data is shown below.

```
public ActionResult ListData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
```

When a user clicks a column header this action method is triggered and the request parameter is filled with "Sorts" attribute showing the column name and sort direction.

For example, a clicked column's name is COLUMN_EXAMPLE in my database table, however in my model its named as ColumnExample. request.Sorts[0].Member returns ColumnExample as expected, however I'm trying to get "COLUMN_EXAMPLE" so that I can use dynamic sql to make proper sorting (not using EF).

There is probably a way to achieve what I want, but couldnt find how to do so, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not related to KendoUI, Maybe this can help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350135/Entity-Framework-Get-mapped-table-name-from-an-ent